# run-length encoding is not working with big numbers

Tags: c++

I have a assingment were I need to code and decode txt files, for example: `hello how are you?` has to be coded as `hel2o how are you?` and `aaaaaaaaaajkle` as `a10jkle`.

```
while ( ! invoer.eof ( ) ) {
        if (kar >= '0' && kar <= '9') {
            counter = kar-48;
            while (counter > 1){
                uitvoer.put(vorigeKar);
                counter--;
            }

        }else if (kar == '/'){
            kar = invoer.get();
            uitvoer.put(kar);
        }else{
            uitvoer.put(kar);
        }
            vorigeKar = kar;

        kar = invoer.get ( );
    }
```

but the problem I have is if need to decode `a12bhr`, the answer is `aaaaaaaaaaaabhr` but I can't seem to get the 12 as number without problems, I also can't use any strings.

Comment: I have to admit I don’t understand the output you’re expecting, even though I know what run-length encoding is. Why is `11123` encoded as `\13\2\3`? What’s the value and what’s the length here? It would also help if you posted code in *English*, since most people here don’t know Dutch (if variable names didn’t matter for reading comprehension we’d just use single-letter names all the time).

Comment: One very important part of understanding code is the naming of the variable. If you post code here on StackOverflow you should consider using English variable names.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol

Answer (score 0):

try to put a repeated character when next is not numeric or end of string.

For prepare this, it needs to make number by parsing string.

about this, I recommend you to find how to convert string to integer in real time at C++.

```cpp
bool isNumeric(char ch) {
    return '0' <= ch && ch <= '9';
}

string decode(const string& s) {
    int counter = 0;
    string result;
    char prevCh;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (isNumeric(s[i])) { // update counter
            counter = counter * 10 + (s[i] - '0');
            if (isNumeric(s[i + 1]) == false || i + 1 == s.length()) {
                // now, put previous character stacked
                while (counter-- > 1) {
                    result.push_back(prevCh);
                }
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            result.push_back(s[i]);
            prevCh = s[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

now, `decode("a12bhr3")` returns `aaaaaaaaaaaabhrrr`. it works well.